# Ubuntu 18.04 slow Wi-Fi connection while using Bluetooth headphones

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, ath9k

I recently changed from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.04. I'm now facing a strange problem that I dont know how to deal with.

Downloading works perfectly until I start listening to some song on Spotify using Bluetooth headphones. When I click play, instantly my download rate goes to zero (or near it).

Here is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0803]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5287] (rev 01)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b573 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 04ca:3014 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 279e:024e  
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy (MTP)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

How to solve this slow connection issue?

Answer (score 10):

The problem is with bluetooth and Wi-Fi working on the same radio frequency.

The coexistence technology is disabled by default for Atheros adapters, probably because long ago it could cause some problems for some old devices.

You can turn it on by running

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf <<< "options ath9k btcoex_enable=1"
```

The setting will be applied after a reboot.

Just in case the setting can be reverted by

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

Comment: The problem keeps the same: turn bluetooth on, wifi speed goes down.

Comment: Just in case someone needs it, I had to replace the `ath9k` with `ath10k_pci`. Verify your kernel module name with `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`. Wifi works fine now. But Bluetooth still has latency/glitch when the device is moved further than 1m from the laptop.

Comment: This solution doesn't work with `ath10k`. It doesn't have `btcoex_enable` parameter.

Answer (score -2):

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell XPS.

My Wi-Fi was slow when using Bluetooth. I've added the following to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and rebooted:

```
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 power_save=0
```

Make sure you restart your computer afterwards.
It's been working fine for me since then.

Comment: This solution is for Intel devices. OP has a QCA one.

Answer (score -2):

This solution worked for me. I'm not getting maximum Wi-Fi speed but it is not degrading audio at least.

Try adding the following line to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` file and reboot the PC:

```
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 swcrypto=1 11n_disable=8
```

- Reference: https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi

Comment: This solution is not applicable, because it is for Intel devices.